# Search for textbits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, cursor, query

Is there a way to search for only parts of text in QGIS.

Imagine I have a field in my attributetable called `myField` and I have several entries there, something like

```
This is awesome
Even more awesome
Hard Faster Stronger
Rolling down
```

Is there a way to search only for `awesome` and get all the rows returned, where `myField` has a cell where the word `awesome` occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve that with select by expression dialogue.

```
"my_field" LIKE '%specific_words%'
```

See this example

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can also use

```
strpos( "myField", 'awesome') > 0
```

and for case insensitive searches

```
strpos( lower("myField"), 'awesome') > 0
```

this is slightly more error-prone as you need to put double quotes around field names and single quotes around string values. I always fall into that trap.

I noticed that a recent version of QGIS (2.12?) has quietly introduced a 'fuzzy matching' category, with functions for **`Hamming Distance`**, **`Levenshtein distance`** and **`Soundex`**. These are useful if you want to match words which are nearly similar, or which sound similar...